# C Shell modulus operator

Tags: linux, csh

I know c shell is very unfriendly but I am stuck with it. So can someone help me with this should-be-a-easy syntax error ? I would like to use modulus operator in c shell. So the command is like this and it keeps giving me syntax error of expr command.

```
set aVAr =`expr $number * 2 % $frequency`
```

I found out I can type "expr 6 % 5 " and "expr 3 * 2". However, I can not use command as "expr 3 * 2 % 5 ". What's wrong with it ? I think CSH should be table to take three operands at the same time ? Thank you very much,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`expr` is a command, not part of csh.  You must escape the `*` to prevent csh from trying to expand it, as in

```
set aVAr =`expr $number \* 2 % $frequency`
```